# OpenJDK - DownloadService2 Service Unsupported in IceTeaWeb

Tags: java, caching, java-web-start, jnlp, icedtea

My company has recently moved to OpenJDK platform. But one of the Applications (JNLP) uses `WebStart`, I tried installing `IcedTeaWeb` but seems cache Management class `DownloadService2` is not supported here. Kindly help here.

I have checked all version of `IcedTeaWeb` but there is no implementation of `DownloadWebService2` in any version of `IcedTeaWeb`.

Below Code in the Application JAR, where my code fails.

```
private void clearCache() {
    try {
DownloadService2 service2 = (DownloadService2)ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.DownloadService2");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Iced-Tea; see https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/icedtea-web/issues/99

It is on the list for implementation.

> Kindly help here.

If you / your company need this to be implemented sooner rather than later, consider contributing some developer effort to the icedtea-web project.

---

I notice that you commented on the issue and got this response:

> We are happy to take a PR against master.

In other words, the IcedTea developers are saying that you could help by sending patches that implement the missing feature".

Talk to your boss.